# Why can't I set QUERY_REWRITE_ENABLED to TRUE?

Tags: oracle, ddl, materialized-views

I'm trying to create a materialized view for a Oracle database but I'm getting this error:

[image]

I've tried to alter the session and the system with "alter session set QUERY_REWRITE_ENABLED = TRUE; " but nothing worked.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

My code is:

```
create materialized view First
refresh complete on commit 
enable query rewrite
as
select id,user_id
from answers;
```

Comment: What edition of Oracle are you using? Not version, but edition, as in "Standard", "Enterprise", etc. See what `select * from v$version` says. Your edition may not support query rewrite.

Comment: I'm using the Express edition

Comment: Then that's your answer. Do a search on https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC109 for the search word "rewrite". You will find that query rewrite is only available in the Enterprise Edition. By the way, if you are just learning, you are allowed to install and use the Enterprise Edition for free. Not so, however, for commercial use.

Comment: Yes, it's just for learning. Thank you!

Comment: Added benefit: If you are learning (and really want to do well in Oracle), you will benefit from starting to learn all the new things in Oracle 12: multi-tenant setup, the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, CROSS APPLY etc. - all in the Enterprise Edition, which will allow you to use many more features than the Express Edition. (Speaking from experience - I went through the same steps you did, and I had the same question about Query Rewrite; someone gave me exactly the info I am sharing here now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP clarified that she is using the Express Edition. With that said:

Do a search on https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#DBLIC110 for the search word "rewrite". You will find that query rewrite is only available in the Enterprise Edition. By the way, if you are just learning, you are allowed to install and use the Enterprise Edition for free. Not so, however, for commercial use.

(The link provided is for Oracle Database version 12.1. The current version available in Express Edition is 11.2; you can find the corresponding documentation for the Oracle 11.2 editions, including the Express edition, with a Google search on "Oracle 11.2 Oracle database editions".)